# React function Component Validation

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, react-forms

I am a beginner in react. I was working on the react function component with forms using hooks. Can anyone please tell how can I apply validation on email text when it is invalid or empty, and disable the continue button if the form is not valid.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
const ForgotPassowrd = () => {
const [emailId, setemailId] = useState("");
const forgotPasswordClick = (event) => {};
return (
<div>
    <div className="NewPassword-form form_wrapper">
        <div className="form-body">
        <form action="#">
        <div>
        <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="password">Email-Id</label>
                <div className="input-group">
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" value={emailId} onChange={(event)=> 
                    setemailId(event.target.value)}/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" onClick={forgotPasswordClick} className="btn btn-lg 
            btn-block">Continue</button>
            </div>
          </form>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    ); 
    };
   export default ForgotPassowrd;
```

Comment: Maybe a good start would be to at least try looking at something on the internet? There's plenty of resources and you shouldn't expect people to do the coding for you.

eg. https://medium.com/@adostes/validating-a-form-in-react-cc29d47e140f

Answer (score 2):

```
    **Try it.This may be helpfull for you! If you can any queries comment below.**
    
    
          const LoginV2 = ({}) => {
    // state
    
    const [loginForm, setLoginForm] = useState({
    email: undefined,
            password: undefined,
            emailValid: false,
            passwordValid: false,
          });
          const [error, setError] = useState({ email: undefined, password: undefined });

// state update        
          const handleLoginForm = (e) => {
            checkValidity(e.target.name, e.target.value);
            setLoginForm({ ...loginForm, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
          };
// validation function        
          const checkValidity = (inputName, inputValue) => {
            switch (inputName) {
              case "email":
                let pattern = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/;
                loginForm.emailValid = pattern.test(inputValue);
                break;
              case "password":
                loginForm.passwordValid = inputValue.length >= 6;
                break;
              default:
                break;
            }
          };
 // form submit       
          const onSubmitLoginForm = () => {
            console.log(loginForm);
            if (!loginForm.emailValid) {
              setError(prevError => {
                  return { 
                      ...prevError, 
                      email: "Invalid Email Address" 
                    }
              }); 
            }
            if (!loginForm.passwordValid) {
              setError(prevError => {
                  return {
                ...prevError,
                password: "Password must be at least six characters long"
              }
            }); 
            }
        
          return (
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form">
                <div class="col span-1-of-2">
                  <div class="username">
                    <p class="login-para text-align-center">LOG IN VIA EMAIL</p>
                    <form method="post" action="#" class="login-form">
                      {error.email && (
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                          <p>
                            {" "}
                            <strong> {alertText} </strong> {error.email}
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      )}
        
                      {error.password && (
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                          <p>
                            {" "}
                            <strong> {alertText} </strong> {error.password}
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      )}
        
                      <div class="info-box">
                        {icon && <i class="fas fa-user-alt login-icon"></i>}
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="email"
                          placeholder="Your Email"
                          onChangeText={(e) => handleLoginForm(e)}
                          inputValue={loginForm.email}
                        />
                      </div>
        
                      <div class="info-box">
                        {icon && <i class="fas fa-user-alt login-icon"></i>}
                        <input
                          type="password"
                          name="password"
                          placeholder="Your Password"
                          onChangeText={(e) => handleLoginForm(e)}
                          inputValue={loginForm.password}
                        />
                      </div>
        
                      <div class="buttons">
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                        <label class="remember" for="#">
                          Remember me
                        </label>
                       <div class="form-btn-disabled" onClick={onSubmitLoginForm} 
                       > 
                         LOGIN NOW 
                       </div>
                      
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        };
        export default LoginV2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below. I have added inline comments for better understanding. Comment your queries if you have any.

```
// Regex to check valid email
const validEmail = /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/g

import React, { useState } from "react";
const ForgotPassowrd = () => {
const [emailId, setemailId] = useState("");
//State to disable/enable continue button
const [disableBtn, setDisableBtn] = useState(false);
const forgotPasswordClick = (event) => {};
const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do whatever you want to do after you click submit button
}
const handleChange = e => {
    setemailId(event.target.value);
    setDisableBtn(validEmail.test(e.target.value));
}
return (
    <div>
    <div className="NewPassword-form form_wrapper">
        <div className="form-body">
        {/* Remove action and use onSubmit handler*/}
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
        <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="password">Email-Id</label>
                <div className="input-group">
                     {/* Introduced name attribute to help you with handleSubmit handler*/}
                    <input name="email" type="text" className="form-control" value={emailId} onChange={(event)=> 
                    setemailId(event.target.value)}/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button onClick={forgotPasswordClick} className="btn btn-lg 
            btn-block" disabled={disableBtn}>Continue</button>
            </div>
          </form>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    ); 
};
export default ForgotPassowrd;
```